# Why NullPointerException is giving on adding a tab?

Tags: android

I am making an application in which I am having three tabs and respective fragment to that.But now I want to add one more tab but when I am adding it there is no issue but when i run my app it throws nullpointerexception.I dont why it is happening so.

Please tell me where I m wrong.

This my Activity in which all tab is there:

```
public class MainActivity extends  Activity { 
        RelativeLayout rl;
        PopupWindow popUp;
        LinearLayout layout;
        TextView tv;
        LayoutParams params;
        LinearLayout mainLayout;
        Button but;
        boolean click = true;

        ActionBar.Tab TabOrder , TabCart,TabHistory;





        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            getOverflowMenu();
            rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            //fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
            actionbar.setTitle("Select To Order");
            actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            //      bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("ORDER").setTabListener((TabListener) this));
            //      bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("CART").setTabListener(this));
            //      bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("HISTORY").setTabListener(this));

            //TabOrder = actionbar.newTab().setText("DEAL");
            TabOrder = actionbar.newTab().setText("ORDER");
            TabCart = actionbar.newTab().setText("CART");
            TabHistory = actionbar.newTab().setText("HISTORY");

            //Fragment FragmentDeal = new FragmentDeal();
            Fragment FragmentOrder = new FragmentOrder();
            Fragment FragmentCart = new FragmentCart();
            Fragment FragmentHistory = new FragmentHistory();


            //TabOrder.setTabListener(new MyTablistenerClass(FragmentDeal));
            TabOrder.setTabListener(new MyTablistenerClass(FragmentOrder));
            TabCart.setTabListener(new MyTablistenerClass(FragmentCart));
            TabHistory.setTabListener(new MyTablistenerClass(FragmentHistory));


            //actionbar.addTab(TabDeal);
            actionbar.addTab(TabOrder);
            actionbar.addTab(TabCart);
            actionbar.addTab(TabHistory);
}

        private void getOverflowMenu() {

            try {
                ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
                Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
                if(menuKeyField != null) {
                    menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                    menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**FragmentOrder**

```
        @SuppressLint({ "ValidFragment", "NewApi" })
        public class FragmentOrder extends Fragment{


            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.g, null);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview,null);
                final GridView listView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);
                listView.setAdapter(new OrderAdapter());
                //listView.setSelection(setselected,true);
                listView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

                listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {


                    @Override
                    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode,
                            MenuItem item) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                        mode.setTitle("Select Items");
                        mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                        return true;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                            int position, long id, boolean checked) {

                        //listView.setLongClickable(false);
                        int selectCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
                        switch (selectCount) {
                        case 1:
                            mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                            break;
                        default:
                            mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount +"items selected");
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                });


                return view;
            }
        }
```

**OrderAdapter**

```
        private class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mThumbIds.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                //CheckableLayout l;

                View myView = convertView;

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);          
                myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_items_ontap, null);


                // Add The Image!!!           
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image_OnTap);
                iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);


                // Add The Text!!!
                TextView tv = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text_onTap);
                tv.setText(names[position] );

                return myView;
            }
        }

        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car
        };

        private String[] names={"ab","cd","ef","gh","ij","kl","mn","","","","","","",""};
```

**FragmentHistory**

```
        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        public class FragmentHistory extends Fragment{

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragmenthistory,   
                        (ViewGroup)  
                        findViewById(R.id.layout_root_history));   


                ListView lv = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listViewHistory); 
                lv.setAdapter(new HistoryListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this));  

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);


                        dlg.setTitle("ORDERID");

                        dlg.setPositiveButton("REORDER",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }

                        })

                        .setNegativeButton("EDIT AND ORDER", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });

                        ListView listView = new ListView(MainActivity.this);

                        listView.setAdapter(new DialogListAdapter(MainActivity.this));

                        dlg.setView(listView);
                        //((Dialog) dlg).setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                        // show it
                        dlg.show();

                    }

                }); 

                return layout;
            }
        }
```

**FragmentCart**

```
        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        public class FragmentCart extends Fragment{

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragmentcart,   
                        (ViewGroup)  
                        findViewById(R.id.layout_root_cart));   


                ListView lv = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listViewCart); 
                lv.setAdapter(new CartListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this));

                //lv.invalidateViews();


                return layout;
            }

        }
```

**FragmentDeal**

```
        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        public class FragmentDeal extends Fragment{


            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentdeal,   
                        (ViewGroup)  
                        findViewById(R.id.layoutdeal));   


                //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.griddeal,null);
                final GridView listView = (GridView) layout.findViewById(R.id.GridDeal);
                listView.setAdapter(new DealAdapter());

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

                return layout;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }
        }

        private class DealAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mThumbIds1.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                //CheckableLayout l;

                View myView = convertView;

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);          
                myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.griddealitems, null);


                // Add The Image!!!           
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_deal_image);
                iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds1[position]);


                // Add The Text!!!
                TextView tv = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_deal_text);
                tv.setText(names1[position] );




                return myView;
            }
            private Integer[] mThumbIds1 = {
                    R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car,
                    R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car

            };

            private String[] names1={"ab","cd","ef","gh"};
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;

        }



        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

            switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent intentForSettings = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsMenu.class);
                startActivity(intentForSettings);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_info:
                Intent intentForInformation = new Intent(MainActivity.this,InformationMenu.class);
                startActivity(intentForInformation);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_ContactUs:
                Intent dial = new Intent();
                String no =  "9579839314";
                dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
                dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ no));
                startActivity(dial); 
                return true;

            }
            return false;

        }

        public class MyTablistenerClass implements android.app.ActionBar.TabListener {

            Fragment fragment1;

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public MyTablistenerClass(Fragment fragment){
                this.fragment1 = fragment;
            }


            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                FragmentTransaction fragMentTra;
                if (tab.getText().equals("DEAL")) {
                    try {
                        rl.removeAllViews();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                FragmentDeal Fram1 = new FragmentDeal();
                    //fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), Fram1);
                    fragMentTra.commit();
                }
                else if (tab.getText().equals("ORDER")) {
                    try {
                        rl.removeAllViews();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    FragmentOrder Fram2 = new FragmentOrder();
                    //fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), Fram2);
                    fragMentTra.commit();
                }

                else if(tab.getText().equals("CART")){
                    try {
                        rl.removeAllViews();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    FragmentCart fram3 = new FragmentCart();
                    //fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram3);
                    fragMentTra.commit();
                }



                else if(tab.getText().equals("HISTORY")){
                    try {
                        rl.removeAllViews();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    FragmentHistory fram4 = new FragmentHistory();
                    //fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram4);
                    fragMentTra.commit();
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        }
    }
```

On adding tabdeal I am facing problem.FragmentDeal is its respective Fragment.If anyone can see where I am wrong tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: Post your error log too, so that others can help you quick.

Comment: Please post the logcat output for the crash (which is almost certainly due to an uncaught exception). 
From Eclipse, you can see the logcat output by opening the Logcat view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//TabOrder = actionbar.newTab().setText("DEAL");
TabOrder = actionbar.newTab().setText("ORDER");
```

You have set both tabs to `TabOrder` . Set the first as `TabDeal`.

EDIT:
Of course you also need to initialize the `TabDeal` here too:

```
ActionBar.Tab TabOrder , TabCart,TabHistory;
```

And by the way, usually only class names start with an uppercase letter. This lead to some confusion for me.